# Counting number of partial overlaps for date range intervals

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table, apply

I need to run a loop over a dataframe with ~150K rows. However, the loop needs to check each row and check a condition that checks every other row in the data set. My code works fine for a toy dataset it produces the correct value but is far far too slow for my actual dataset. I let it run for several hours and it still never finished. so I'm hoping someone has a better idea how to approach this.

```
#R version 3.5.1 Windows 64-bit

#Example dataset
my_df <- data.frame("PERSON" = c("A","A","A","B","A","A","B"),
                    "DATE_START" = c("2019-01-15","2019-01-10","2019-01-20","2019-01-19","2018-12-20","2018-03-03","2019-05-01"),
                    "DATE_FINISH" = c("2019-01-30","2019-01-18","2019-02-05","2019-01-23","2019-02-10","2018-04-01","2019-06-06")
                    )
#Each row is a task that the assigned person is working on
my_df
   PERSON   DATE_START DATE_FINISH
1       A   2019-01-15  2019-01-30
2       A   2019-01-10  2019-01-18
3       A   2019-01-20  2019-02-05
4       B   2019-01-19  2019-01-23
5       A   2018-12-20  2019-02-10
6       A   2018-03-03  2018-04-01
7       B   2019-05-01  2019-06-06
```

What I want to know is FOR row 1, how many other tasks does Person A have overlap between his start and finish dates? (including the row its on)

So the answer I'm looking for is

```
   PERSON   DATE_START DATE_FINISH  NUMBER_OF_TASKS
1       A   2019-01-15  2019-01-30  4
2       A   2019-01-10  2019-01-18  3
3       A   2019-01-20  2019-02-05  3
4       B   2019-01-19  2019-01-23  1
5       A   2018-12-20  2019-02-10  4
6       A   2018-03-03  2018-04-01  1
7       B   2019-05-01  2019-06-06  1
```

So this basically says for Row 1, person A had 4 open tasks

I tried created list element for every row that includes the range of dates as numeric values and then to check if there is overlap I used %in% operator to compare the unlisted ranges

I've done something similar using the lapply function(not shown here) but same issue it just takes forever to execute.

```
##This is what I currently have

temp_list <- list()
num_open_tasks <- c()
open_work_cc <- c()

##Create a list of length = nrow(my_df)
##Each element in the list is a range of dates coerced to numeric
for(i in 1:nrow(my_df)){
  temp_list[[i]] <- as.numeric(my_df$DATE_START[i]) : 
                    as.numeric(my_df$DATE_FINISH[i])
}


for(i in 1:nrow(my_df)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(my_df)){

##If elements from the temp_list overlap by 5 days, the overlap = 5
##I'm just checking if the overlap is greater than 0 (is there any overlap at all)
##And if the tasks belongs to the same person or not    
open_work_cc[j] <- ifelse(sum(unlist(temp_list[[i]]) %in% 
                              unlist(temp_list[[j]])) > 0 &
                              my_df$PERSON[i] == my_df$PERSON[j] 
                              ,1,0
                           )
open_work_cc_total <- sum(open_work_cc)

  }
  num_open_tasks[i] <- open_work_cc_total

}
my_df <- cbind(my_df, num_open_tasks)
```

This method returns my desired column populated with the correct values.
But I imagine there is a more elegant and significantly faster method using some form of split/apply/combine. Any and all help is appreciated thanks

Comment: If you write exact same logic with Julia language - you will not have this speed problem.

Comment: ... and if you try `as.numeric(my_df$DATE_START[i])` as-is, you will have many logic problems (i.e., lots of `NA`).

Comment: Learning Julia is on the road map! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foverlaps` in `data.table` is probably going to be the fastest approach in R. I think the following code does what you want:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)

my_df[, DATE_START_N:=as.numeric(as.Date(DATE_START))]
my_df[, DATE_FINISH_N:=as.numeric(as.Date(DATE_FINISH))]

setkey(my_df, PERSON, DATE_START_N,DATE_FINISH_N)

my_df[,NUMBER_OF_TASKS:=foverlaps(my_df,my_df,which=TRUE)[,.N,by=xid]$N]
my_df
```

For a bit more clarity: `foverlaps(my_df,my_df,which=TRUE)` does a self-join on date-range within `PERSON` (the join is determined by `setkey`). Note that the default argument for `type` of interval join for foverlaps is `"any"` which is a partial match on intervals: i.e., what you want here.

Specifying `which=TRUE` will just provide the indices of matches in x and y (rather than the actual joined data which is unnecessary here).  The call to `foverlaps` returns an object of class `data.table` which is then immediately aggregated to take the number of rows in each group defined by `xid` (which are just rows of `my_df`) using the bracket function call `[,.N,by=xid]`. These counts are extracted into a vector with `$N` and assigned to a new column `NUMBER_OF_TASKS` in `my_df`.

Comment: `data.table::foverlaps` was my first thought, and it looks like this is the right way to attack it here (esp with `as.Date` working for us :-).

Comment: This worked like a charm! Took about 2 seconds to run the whole thing. Thank you very much, shows me I need to learn a lot more data.table

Comment: I don't know enough of the magic of data.table, sadly, but this was a life saver, thanks! I didn't need it grouped by person, and so I simply omitted the person bit and I needed it exactly by the minute (and my data is ymd_hms-format):
```
setkey(my_df, DATE_START, DATE_FINISH)
```

This worked like a charm for me, summing amount of simultaneous logins in a db :)